# Angularjs - Play Framework. Unable to receive response in Http post

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.0, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

A simple http response is not received in angularjs, but returns successfully on a curl request. I have enabled CORS and the post params are received in the server but response returned is always blank.

Here is my request part:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/adminAuth',
            data: $.param({email:username,password:password})
            }).then(function(response,status){
                auth.user=response.data;
                $cookieStore.put('user',auth.user);
                return auth.user;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

The error printed in console as:
[image: console error logged][image: error expansion]

Comment: Will you try to add this line
 data: {
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                email:username,password:password
            },

Comment: @Sunny_Sid I got the same blank response.

Comment: Please look into my post below. It might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this thing using following code:-

```js
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    ids: Id,
                    Action: actionid,
                    isSelectedAll: true
                },
                url: 'Doctor/Doctor/AppointmentStatusUpdate',
                responseType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // do anything
  })
```

Comment: I have set the content type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. It is sending requests as OPTIONS if it is set to 'application/json' and ends up as 404.

Comment: Make sure your controller should have anonymous attribute and Method name should be define by 
[httpPost]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the debug message, it seems that you are trying to make a request to a different origin. You will need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*`, or something along those lines. The problem is that your browser is blocking the response (for [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). I don't know which API you're using, but in Scala you would need to add to your response the following:

```
Ok("This is my response")
  .withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*")
```